# Simple android 2.2 programming question

Tags: android

Sorry I'm really new to this, but I can't find anything in the docs.

I have 3 .class files that I'm attempting to use in an android 2.2 project, but I don't know where to put them so that I can import them, for some reason Eclipse won't allow me to put them in the android 2.2 folder (it seems to be unwriteable) So where can I put these class files? Can I put them in the src folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do in this cases is saving those class files in a **standard** JAR file and including it into your project build path.